# Count database record grouped by two criteria (date & Vehicle number) and display error in index page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to asp.net MVC. I hope anyone can help me with this.

This is a program for maintaining records of fuel expenses for multiple vehicles.
I would like to create a message to appear if there are more than 5 records of fuel entry for a specific vehicle in a month. For example, When the count of fuel entry record for a vehicle reaches more than 5 in a month "June 2020" an error message should be displayed on the index page or home page. I have been searching for this but had no luck.

The relevant bits from the Model, Controller, and View is below.

**Vehicle list Model:**

```
namespace VehicleReg2.Models
{
    public class VehicleList
    {   [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        public string VType { get; set; }
        public string RegNumber { get; set; }
        public string ModelMake { get; set; }
}}
```

**Fuel Model:**

```
namespace VehicleReg2.Models
{
    public class Fuel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal FAmount { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime FDate { get; set; }

        public VehicleList VehicleList { get; set; }
        public byte VehicleListId { get; set; }

        public double FQty { get; set; }     
    }}
```

**Fuel Controller Index:**

```
public ViewResult Index()
        {var fuel = _context.Fuels.Include(c => c.VehicleList).ToList();
         return View(fuel);
        }
```

Comment: Can you search Count Linq

Comment: I did try Linq but was not successful in using single month criteria. Could you suggest me any link that helps with my case?

Comment: I will try look into this when I have some time tomorrow, but a few notes: 1. You should use the ViewBag to store the result of your query. 2. The count lambda expression would be something like this `db.Fuels.Where(x => x.VehicleList.RegNumber.Count() > 5);`

Comment: @JacobHallgarth I had tried a similar expression but in my case need to involve the per month 5 count condition ("FDate").  For every month if entries cross over 5 count a simple error should be displayed in the Index view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to group by `Date` and then make your `Count` control after. I didn't try the below query but it should be similar to what you want;

```
db.Fuels.GroupBy(x => x.FDate.Date)
            .Where(x => x.ToList().VehicleList.RegNumber.Count() > 5)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Below query finds all the `Fuel` entries (more than 5) for a spesific `Vehicle` in each `month`

```
db.Fuels.GroupBy(x => new { x.FDate.Date, x.VehicleListId })
            .Where(x => x.Count() > 5)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: I am sorry but it seems to end up with an error **"The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"**. Any advice?

Comment: Please try;  `db.Fuels.GroupBy(x => new { EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.FDate), x.VehicleListId }).Where(x => x.Count() > 5).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the immediate reply. I did use **DbFunctions.TruncateTime** but got this error **Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source**

Comment: I used your code little modified in view part and got the perfect output. Is it possible to make it in controller `@foreach (var fuel in Model.GroupBy(x => new { Month = x.FDate.Month, Year = x.FDate.Year, Vehicle = x.VehicleList.RegNumber }).Where(x => x.Count() > 5).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList())){<tr<td>@fuel.Key.Vehicle</td><td>@fuel.Key.Month / @fuel.Key.Year</td></tr>}`

Comment: Nice to hear that!

Comment: Thank you for the help. What changes should I do in controller and view?

Comment: You can do just the same thing and store the result in a viewbag. After, you can loop through the viewbag data just like you did in the view.